# How to get more space on XBox one without removing anything?

Tags: xbox-one

So i have 13.4 GB's left on my XBox One S, and i recently purchased a game that is 40 GB+, and all of the games i have i do not really want to remove... So i was just wondering how do i do this and is it possible? I have had a bit of a google but nothing i have found actually answers my question, some things point you in the "yes" direction, but it never actually tells you if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use an external storage device.

The Xbox One supports installing games to an external storage device, and the Xbox One S is no exception.

According to [Xbox Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/storage/manage-storage):

> To use external storage with Xbox games and apps, your hard drive must:
>
> - Hold 128 GB or more
> - Connect via USB 3.0/3.1
>
> When you first connect, Xbox will prompt you to format your device. You can use it for Xbox games and apps, or for personal media such as pictures, music, and video. (Xbox will treat devices that don’t meet the above requirements as media storage.)

Since the Xbox One will format the external device, make sure to move any existing data to another storage device before connecting it to the Xbox One.